# casefold() function is not working when using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of tweets which contain the columns id, text, lang, created_at and location. I am performing normalization on the text column and I need to make all the text in lowercase.

The text column contains 6 rows.

```
Elephants ruined again fields and kills a farmer
SFF Friday night build
Dont
Hi
i will forever love and her family
The only way Republicans know
```

These are some tweets that I captured from Twitter. When I simply apply

```
df.["text"].str.casefold()
```

it does not work. The output is the same as the input with no changes. I tried lower() as well which also doesn't work. How can I perform casefolding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
x = '''Elephants ruined again fields and kills a farmer
SFF Friday night build
Dont
Hi
i will forever love and her family
The only way Republicans know'''
df = pd.DataFrame(x.split('\n'), columns=['text'])
#*** use str.lower() ***
df.text = df.text.str.lower()
print(df)
```

```
0    elephants ruined again fields and kills a farmer
1                              sff friday night build
2                                                dont
3                                                  hi
4                  i will forever love and her family
5                       the only way republicans know
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: HI, this works thank you, but do you know if this can be applied when there are a lot of rows in the text column. For example over 20000 tweets.

Comment: Should work up to limit of system memory.  Someone smarter will need to talk about performance...  You can always split the work into N cycles if memory becomes an issue.